# Windows API: WM_COPYDATA infinite loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, winapi

I have a project for school and I got an error which I don't know how to fix.
I am currently using Visual Studio 2015, and use a console application.
My project is: I need to make an application in which a process sends to another process, the containings of a text file, line with line. One line is sent from 5 to 5 seconds. The receiver will get line for 35 seconds, and write them in a file, then the receiver will send a message to the sender that the lines have been received.
I have tried to make this project using the PCOPYDATASTRUCT and WM_COPYDATA, and I read and write from files with fgets and fputs.
My problem is that it goes into an infinite loop, creating a 1gb text file in like a few seconds, and copying only the first line. I have tried to fix what i could, but nothing is changing. 
Hope you can help me, thank you.
Here is the send application:

```
    #undef UNICODE
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAXLEN 100

const int ID_BUTTON = 1;
const int ID_EDIT = 2;
FILE *pFile;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static char szAppName[] = "Send";
    HWND        hwnd;
    MSG         msg;
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclass; // obiectul instantiat din structura WNDCLASSEX

    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);//Dimensiunea structurii
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //Stilul ferestrei
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; // Procedura de fereastra care trateaza mesajele
                                    // Doua câmpuri care permit rezervarea de spatiu suplimentar in structura class, respectiv structura window.
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance; //Identificatorul instantei ferestrei
                                    //Stabileste o pictograma pentru toate ferestrele create pe baza clasei window
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    //Stabileste o pictograma pentru cursor
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    //Specifica culoarea de fundal a ferestrei
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL; // Specifica meniul feresterei
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName; // Specifica numele feresterei
    wndclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    //Inregistrarea clasei de fereastra
    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    // Crearea ferestrei pe baza clasei de fereastra
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,         // window class name
        "Aplicatia Send",     // window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     // window style
        100,           // initial x position
        100,           // initial y position
        1200,           // initial x size
        800,           // initial y size
        NULL,                    // parent window handle
        NULL,                    // window menu handle
        hInstance,               // program instance handle
        NULL);                   // creation parameters

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow); // afiseaza fereastra pe ecran
                                //transmite catre WndProc un mesaj de tip WM_PAINT, care are ca rezultat
                                //redesenarea ferestrei, adica reactualizarea zonei client a ferestrei
    UpdateWindow(hwnd); // 

                        // preia si distribuie mesaje pana se primeste WM_QUIT
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); // traduce mesajul
        DispatchMessage(&msg); // transmite mesajul catre procedura de fereastra
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HDC hdc; //contextul grafic
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; // o variabila la structura de desenare
    RECT rect; //obiect dreptunghi
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    HWND hwndReceive;
    static int cxChar, cyChar;
    static HWND hEdit, hButtonOk;
    COPYDATASTRUCT cs;
    char mystring[100];
    SYSTEMTIME LocalTime;
    hwndReceive = FindWindow("Recieve", "RecieveMessage");

    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: //operatii ce se executa la crearea ferestrei
    {
        pFile = fopen("fis.txt", "r");
        if (pFile == NULL)

        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Nu am gasit fisierul sursa!", "Eroare SEND!", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT));
        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
        cyChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        hButtonOk = CreateWindow("button", "Trimite date", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            10 * cxChar, cyChar * 8, 50 * cxChar, 2 * cyChar,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

        hEdit = CreateWindow("edit", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER,
            40 * cxChar, cyChar * 25, 60 * cxChar, 10 * cyChar,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

    }
    return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {

        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON)
        {

            if (hwndReceive != NULL)
            {

                GetLocalTime(&LocalTime);
                printf("Timpul sistem este: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", LocalTime.wHour, LocalTime.wMinute, LocalTime.wSecond);

                int TimpPornire = LocalTime.wHour * 3600 + LocalTime.wMinute * 60 + LocalTime.wSecond;

                GetLocalTime(&LocalTime);
                while ((fgets(mystring, 100, pFile) != NULL))
                {

                    cs.cbData = strlen(mystring);
                    cs.lpData = mystring;
                    SendMessage(hwndReceive, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hwnd, (LPARAM)&cs);
                    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, ID_EDIT, "Se trimit datele...");
                    Sleep(5000);
                    GetLocalTime(&LocalTime);
                    int TimpCurent = LocalTime.wHour * 3600 + LocalTime.wMinute * 60 + LocalTime.wSecond;
                    if (TimpCurent - TimpPornire >= 35)
                    {
                        SetDlgItemText(hwnd, ID_EDIT, "Au trecut 35 de secunde!");
                        break;
                    }

                }

                fclose(pFile);
                CloseHandle(hwnd);

            }

            else

            {
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Nu am gasit procesul fiu(Recieve)!", "Eroare SEND!", MB_OK);
                return 0;
            }


        }

    }
        return 0;



    case WM_DESTROY://operatii ce se executa la distrugerea ferestrei
        PostQuitMessage(0); // insereaza un mesaj de incheiere in coada de mesaje
        return 0;
    }
    // Alte mesaje sunt trimise catre functia implicita de tratare
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

and the receive application is this:

```
 #undef UNICODE
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAXLEN 100


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static char szAppName[] = "Recieve";
    HWND        hwnd;
    MSG         msg;
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclass; // obiectul instantiat din structura WNDCLASSEX

    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);//Dimensiunea structurii
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //Stilul ferestrei
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; // Procedura de fereastra care trateaza mesajele
                                    // Doua câmpuri care permit rezervarea de spatiu suplimentar in structura class, respectiv structura window.
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance; //Identificatorul instantei ferestrei
                                    //Stabileste o pictograma pentru toate ferestrele create pe baza clasei window
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    //Stabileste o pictograma pentru cursor
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    //Specifica culoarea de fundal a ferestrei
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL; // Specifica meniul feresterei
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName; // Specifica numele feresterei
    wndclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    //Inregistrarea clasei de fereastra
    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    // Crearea ferestrei pe baza clasei de fereastra
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,         // window class name
        "RecieveMessage",     // window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     // window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x position
        CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y position
        CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x size
        CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y size
        NULL,                    // parent window handle
        NULL,                    // window menu handle
        hInstance,               // program instance handle
        NULL);                   // creation parameters

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow); // afiseaza fereastra pe ecran
                                //transmite catre WndProc un mesaj de tip WM_PAINT, care are ca rezultat
                                //redesenarea ferestrei, adica reactualizarea zonei client a ferestrei
    UpdateWindow(hwnd); // 

                        // preia si distribuie mesaje pana se primeste WM_QUIT
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); // traduce mesajul
        DispatchMessage(&msg); // transmite mesajul catre procedura de fereastra
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HDC hdc; //contextul grafic
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; // o variabila la structura de desenare
    RECT rect; //obiect dreptunghi
    static char szBufferPaint[MAXLEN] = "Astept datele...", szBufferReceive[MAXLEN];
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcs;
    FILE *rFile;
    pcs = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;

    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: //operatii ce se executa la crearea ferestrei

        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT://operatii ce se executa la desenarea ferestrei
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); //Obtinerea contextului grafic
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect); //Obtinerea suprafeţei de desenare
                                    //Scrierea unui text în fereastră
        DrawText(hdc, szBufferPaint, -1, &rect,
            DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); //Eliberarea contextului grafic
        return 0;

    case WM_COPYDATA:
    {

        rFile = fopen("test.txt", "w");
                pcs = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;
                strncpy_s(szBufferReceive, (char*)pcs->lpData, pcs->cbData);
                fputs(szBufferReceive, rFile);
                break;
            CloseHandle(hwnd);
            fclose(rFile);
    }
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY://operatii ce se executa la distrugerea ferestrei
        PostQuitMessage(0); // insereaza un mesaj de incheiere in coada de mesaj
        return 0;
    }
    // Alte mesaje sunt trimise catre functia implicita de tratare
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: In your receiving application you have `while (szBufferReceive!=NULL)`..

Comment: When you debugged this, which side is looping? Is the sender app continually posting messages, or is the receiver app acting like it's continually receiving messages?

Comment: `while (szBufferReceive!=NULL)` basically says "while the address of the buffer I'll store data into isn't NULL, repeat the following block of code". The buffer's address will always be non-null, so this while loop is infinite. A better approach may be to check the `pcs->cbData` field to ensure it isn't 0.

Comment: @Kenney - Oh yeah!  It's designed to loop continually:(

Comment: @Kenney It's the sender.

Comment: I think it's the receiver - once you get 1 WM_COPYDATA message you loop infinitely. You should probably save 1 line of text for each WM_COPYDATA (since that is how you send it).

Comment: Maybe it's both:(  OP - get out your debugger and do some more work.

Comment: @Kenney Hmm, and how can I save one line for each WM_COPYDATA? Or what condition should i put so that when one line was put in the file, to put the next line?

Comment: Ok, i edit some few things.

Comment: Ok. Sender looks better but you still have an infinite `while` loop inside `case WM_COPYDATA`. That `pcs->cbData` will not change in that loop (because `lParam` doesn't change), unless you get another `WM_COPYDATA` message. Try this: `case WM_COPYDATA: fputs( pcs->lpData, rFile ); break;`. And, close the file in `WM_DESTROY`. You can send another message (perhaps a `WM_COPYDATA` with a zero-length payload) to indicate the transfer is complete.

Comment: @Kenney It doesn't let me in the fputs to put pcs->lpData, because the function needs a const char* as the first parameter and pcs->lpData is a PVOID. And now, if I try to run it, I get a Debug Assertion Failed linked to fputs, and it says : Expression: stream != nullptr

Comment: Oh sorry, perhaps use `cbData` instead (it just seems to me the `strncpy_s` is not needed), but the point is not to `while()` inside that `case`, and not close the file there (unless you open it there too).

Comment: It doesn't let me put in the fputs cbData or lpData, that is why i used first a strncpy_s, to copy the line that was received in a string, and then use that string in the fputs function. I now open the file and close the file in the WM_COPYDATA and i don't use a while anymore, but now i get the a Debug Assertion Failed linked to fputs, and it says : Expression: stream != nullptr. I will edit the receive application from the main post. The sender freezes and gives this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work locally. Here's a diff:

**sender**

No real change, except supporting to send the file multiple times (adding `fseek` and moving `fclose`). I also removed the `<iostream>` and `using namespace std` - this is C++ and not used or needed here.

```
diff --git a/sender.c b/sender.c
index a0a29a3..b5caf62 100644
--- a/sender.c
+++ b/sender.c
@@ -3,9 +3,7 @@
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
-#include <iostream>
 #include <windows.h>
-using namespace std;
 #define MAXLEN 100

 const int ID_BUTTON = 1;
@@ -128,6 +126,8 @@ LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
                 int TimpPornire = LocalTime.wHour * 3600 + LocalTime.wMinute * 60 + LocalTime.wSecond;

                 GetLocalTime(&LocalTime);
+
+                fseek( pFile, 0, SEEK_SET );
                 while ((fgets(mystring, 100, pFile) != NULL))
                 {

@@ -146,7 +146,6 @@ LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

                 }

-                fclose(pFile);
                 CloseHandle(hwnd);

             }
@@ -167,6 +166,7 @@ LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)


     case WM_DESTROY://operatii ce se executa la distrugerea ferestrei
+        fclose(pFile);
         PostQuitMessage(0); // insereaza un mesaj de incheiere in coada de mesaje
         return 0;
     }
```

**receiver**

Also very little change: moved the `break;` down so `fclose` is actually called, and using flag `"a+"` to append to the file instead of overwriting it.

```
diff --git a/receiver.c b/receiver.c
index 74434ba..f068661 100644
--- a/receiver.c
+++ b/receiver.c
@@ -3,9 +3,7 @@
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
-#include <iostream>
 #include <windows.h>
-using namespace std;
 #define MAXLEN 100


@@ -95,13 +93,12 @@ LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     case WM_COPYDATA:
     {

-        rFile = fopen("test.txt", "w");
-                pcs = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;
-                strncpy_s(szBufferReceive, (char*)pcs->lpData, pcs->cbData);
-                fputs(szBufferReceive, rFile);
-                break;
-            CloseHandle(hwnd);
-            fclose(rFile);
+        rFile = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
+        pcs = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;
+        fputs((char*)pcs->lpData, rFile);
+        fclose(rFile);
+        CloseHandle(hwnd);
+        break;
     }
         return 0;
```

Note that it's bad practice to `sleep` inside event handlers - the window/application is unresponsive during that time. Also I'm unsure what the purpose of the `CloseHandle(hwnd)` is - not sure that's needed or does anything.

Comment: Wow, thank you, this is helpful. Yes, i noticed that the sleep command is making the windows unresponsive, but my teacher asked me to use this command, so it's not an issue. Also, i found out that using the fclose(rfile) is enough, i won't need the CloseHandle anymore. I'm gonna try your code and see if it works.